# Our 404 page loads only once every 10 refreshes~

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

https://www.cruise118.com/h/

We enter an incorrect URL and the web page throws up a generic browser 404 page - we have our own 404 page, which will load once every handful of refreshes.

On local copy, it works perfectly fine every time.

Furthermore, it used to work on live every time. We have found one example of an old URL which will consistently load the 404 page every time:

https://www.cruise118.com/cruise-line/oceania/?pagenumber=2&resultsperpage=20&destinationfilter=&monthfilter=&cruiseLinefilter=

We're using codeigniter v.2.0

Comment: Sounds like some caching issue. So you have server side caches in place? Clear and restart them. Restart your http server in case there are child processes not having picked up changes yet.

Comment: like you are using varnish cache tool, so @arkascha is right

Comment: We have tried restarting varnish again just to be sure, and also the web server. The problem persists but thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved,
background: we use a Content Delivery Network,
we pointed the DNS records from that to our own servers and suddenly our 404 is a custom message again